# Contribution imports have stopped working

Tags: contributions, import, field-mapping

I have been importing contributions from a .csv file every month for a couple of years. It recently stopped working for me. I get the following error message:

"Please correct the following errors in the form fields below:
Missing required contact matching fields. email(weight 10) (Sum of all weights should be greater than or equal to threshold: 10)."

Email is one of the imported fields.

Comment: It sounds like the matching rule you are using has email weighted less than 10, which is causing the issue.

Comment: We face the same issue - it must have been an update of CiviCRM or some extension as the same field mapping worked for years now. @JenniSimonis - it would be helpful to get some more details as you just say the same as the error message just in other words :) I still have no clu where I set the weight

Comment: I just found out that in our case the message appears due to dedupe rule "IndividualStrict4-4" (Id: 4) but when I go the edit page of this rule I cannot change anything: /civicrm/contact/deduperules?action=update&id=4

Comment: You'd need to look to see which dedupe rule you're using when you do your import. You choose it as part of that process. Then you'll need to go to that rule and edit it. If you're unable to edit it, then that is either a permission issue or a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue here with a workaround: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3939

And there is already a pull request to fix this issue: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/24838

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm unsure what that the last 2 steps mean on the work around. Are you able to provide any explantion please?

Comment: You should ask them - I did not describe the workaround and I did not try it yet.